# How do you remove leading character before a specific character?

Tags: php, sql-server, json

```
/* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:Cambria;    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}  hi
```

I have this value in an MS SQL table.  I have successfully used PHP to connect to it and run a query to grab it and throw it out to a JSON format.

Assuming that I only have "read-only" access or that I do not want to modify anything in the database, what are my options to remove everything before (and including) the '}'.  In short, display only "hi".

I'm fine with modifying it during "SELECT", at the PHP level, or even at the JSON output.  A quick note regarding how the data is store at each level.

Much appreciated if anyone can help me with this.

---

Edit: Sorry for the lack of information, I have edited this to include more information.

@ SQL: It's data type is "text".

```
MSSQL 2012 Field Type: Text
```

@ PHP: It's in an array.

`ie. Array ( [0] => data1 [1] => data2 [2] => /* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable  {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:Cambria;    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}  hi )`

Comment: In SQL, `CHARINDEX('}', colname)` will find the string position, `SUBSTRING(colname, CHARINDEX('}', colname), LEN(colname))` will give you everything after }. `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` as appropriate.

Comment: If it's `TEXT` and you want to do it in SQL, convert to `VARCHAR(4000)`. e.g. `SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName), CHARINDEX('}', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName)) + 1, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName))))) FROM tblName`

Comment: Thank you ZLK.  That worked quite well.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it's TEXT and you want to do it in SQL, convert to VARCHAR(4000).
>   e.g. SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName),
>   CHARINDEX('}', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName)) + 1,
>   LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), colName))))) FROM tblName – ZLK Jan 27 at
>   2:47

This worked perfectly. Might be a problem for those needing more than 4000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str='/* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:Cambria;    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}  hi ';

$pos = strpos($str, '}'); //find position of }

echo trim(substr($str,$pos+1)); //extract everything from } to end of string (trim optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$old = '/* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-priority:99;  mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:12.0pt;   font-family:Cambria;    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;  mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;   mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;  mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}  hi      ';
$new = trim(preg_replace( '/.+}([^}]+)$/','\1',$old ));

echo $new;
```